# Javascript replace and $ sign in newSubStr

Tags: javascript, string, replace, escaping

I got a simple javascript code :

```
'test1 {0} test2 test3'.replace('{0}', "test$'")
```

I expected the result to be `test1 test$' test2 test3`. But the result is `test1 test test2 test3 test2 test3`

This is absolutely normal. According to the mozilla documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

The `$'` sequence has a signification in this case.

But i want to replace `{0}` with `test$'` exactly. I don't want the `$'` sequence to be replace by something else. I have tried many ways :

```
'test1 {0} test2 test3'.replace('{0}', "test\$\'")
'test1 {0} test2 test3'.replace('{0}', "test\\$\\'")
'test1 {0} test2 test3'.replace('{0}', "test\u0024\u0027")
'test1 {0} test2 test3'.replace('{0}', "test\$'")
```

But nothing works.

How can i escape the `$'` sequence to avoid Firefox using it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the page you cited:

> $$    Inserts a "$".

So:

```
'test1 {0} test2 test3'.replace('{0}', "test$$'")
```

This [works for me on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ndBQY/).

Comment: Ok, i'm just stupid. The answer was just under my eyes. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

An option is to use a regex as your first argument:

```
'test1 {0} test2 test3'.replace(/\{0\}/, 'test$')
```

works: http://jsfiddle.net/Znwj2/

Comment: -1: [Not true; a string is acceptable for a string replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). And your code does not match the OP's; his replacement text is `test$'`, not `test$`, and _that_ is the cause of the issue.

Comment: When you say 'not true' do you mean this doesn't work?  When I say you need I meant to say an option is.

Comment: It's still wrong, though. Look closely. Your output is missing a `'`.